# Can't downgrade from Ubuntu 16 to Ubuntu 14 (Boot Problems)

Tags: boot, downgrade

I've installed Ubuntu 16 because that was the DVD I had at hand... Although Ubuntu 14 is the version we use at work... What happens here, is that it throws a lot of errors when I tried to set up my development environment... So I got an usb with Ubuntu 14 and tried to install it but I could (cant enter the Bios nor boot the computer in that pen or dvd)...

Do I explain myself ?... Is there any guide to remove or format but doing the process from linux... because from windows I didn't have any problems...

Comment: You can install Ubuntu 14.04 from scratch.

Comment: Do you know how ?. Because that is what I want... As I couldn't do it from scratch I look forward to downgrade... But how I will supossed to do it If I can't open the bios ?... Thankx PIlot ! :D

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried pressing F9 {some cases F8) for boot options? There you can select to boot up via usb directly

Comment: I remember pressing all the possible keys on the keyboard... But I'll try this again... It seemed, when I tried, as if the bios was blocked... Weird ! :S
Thankxx dude